# Local storage with api, vanilla js

Tags: javascript, local-storage

To make this short and sweet my code is

```
const searchBox = document.querySelector(".search-box");
searchBox.addEventListener("keypress", setQuery);

function setQuery(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    getResults(searchBox.value);
    searchBox.value = "";
  }
}

function getResults(query) {
  localStorage.setItem("location", searchBox.value);
  let storedItem = localStorage.getItem("location");
  console.log(storedItem);
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${storedItem}&units=imperial&APPID=${api.key}`)
    .then((weather) => {
      return weather.json();
    })
    .then(displayResults);
}
```

This all works great and the city that is typed into the search box is stored into the local storage just fine and if page is refreshed I can look in the google chrome app section and see it still in local storage.

After the page refresh tho the app resets to the default landing page.

I'm thinking I need to use something like window.onload = function()

the problem is if I'm setting the storedItem I can't access outside of the getResults function.

any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want the last search term to be automatically load into `getResult()` after the page loads?

Comment: Realistically. Yes. In the app you can type your city say Tokyo. If I refresh the page I would like Tokyo to still be showing. Until a new search query is entered.

Comment: OK try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71166726/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove `localStorage.setItem("location", searchBox.value);` from `getResults()` and add it to `setQuery()`.
- Next, add this to `getResults()`

  ```
  let qry = query == undefined ? 
  localStorage.getItem("location") : query;
  ```

  This means if there isn't any query passed to `getResults(query)` then get the value from `localStorage` under the key `"location"`.
- Finally bind the `DOMContentLoaded` event to `document` and `getResults()` as event handler,

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getResults)
  ```

```js
const searchBox = document.querySelector(".search-box");
searchBox.addEventListener("keypress", setQuery);

function setQuery(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    getResults(searchBox.value);
    localStorage.setItem("location", searchBox.value);
    searchBox.value = "";
  }
}

function getResults(query) {
  let qry = query == undefined ? localStorage.getItem("location") : query;
  console.log(qry);
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${qry}&units=imperial&APPID=${api.key}`)
    .then((weather) => {
      return weather.json();
    })
    .then(displayResults);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getResults)
```

Comment: So I did try this solution, maybe something I'm doing is wrong because when I run the app and search i do see it show in localStorage. if I refresh the page or close it. then reopen the value is no longer in localStorage.

Comment: The only time the localStorage is overwriten is when a user hits return while focused in the searchbar.

Comment: Ah! I know what it is! In `setQuery()` put this line last or remove it `searchBox.value = "";`

Comment: Ahhh genius! that is fixing the issue where it was clearing the local storage, makes sense in hindsight. Still have the issue where the page is not pulling up the localstorage. It just resets to default still. any ideas?

Comment: ahhh I got it! added the () to getResults. IE
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getResults())

Comment: That's actually correct -- when you are binding an event handler you don't want use those parenthesis becuase that will invoke the function immediately and that's not what event handlers do because they wait. Try removing that line and just have `getResults()` out there by itself.